# Select a row as JSON in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a straightforward way to put entire row from one Postgres table into a JSON column in another table?

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm looking to do. Let's say I've got a table `people`, with name, age, and data columns:

```
column type
-----------
name   text
age    int
data   json
```

I'd like to merge in my table of `2012_customers`, which has a lot more columns. How would I stuff all those extra columns into the JSON column of `people`, preserving the column names as the data keys? Here's some pseudo-SQL for that:

```
insert into people
select 
name,
age,
all_fields_as_json() as json
from customers_2012
```

Comment: Does `row_to_json` not do what you need?

Comment: That or `to_json` probably does what I want, but I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax for the example above.

Comment: try `select name, age, row_to_json(customers_2012) from customers_2012` as your select part.

Comment: Got that just as you posted! Thanks! If you want to post the answer I'll remove mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this situation, the correct syntax is to use `row_to_json(table_name)`:

```
insert into people
select 
name,
age,
row_to_json(customers_2012) as json
from customers_2012
```

Comment: Small addition: When qualifying the schema on the FROM statement, the schema does not get qualified in the row_to_json() call

This means it looks like this
```sql
select row_to_json(mytable) as json from other_schema.mytable;
```